# Why could Goten and Gohan not resist the Baby controlling them while Trunks was able to?

Tags: dragon-ball-gt

In *Dragon Ball GT* episode 26, it seems like Goten is weakened before being taken over by Baby, but was Trunks not in a similar condition, i.e. weakened? In DBGT episode 24, yet he was able to resist and succeeded to stop Baby from taking over him.

Why couldn't Goten do the same? Gohan, on the other side, wasn't hurt a bit; how could he be taken over so easily?

Answer (score 1):

Trunks has always been stronger than Goten.

When they learned to merge, in the Buu Saga, this was clearly proven, since as Piccolo said, Trunks had to lower their power level, to get equal to Goten, and Goten needed to increase his so that both were in balance and can merge.

So maybe, because of that difference in power, Goten could be controlled, but not Trunks.

Comment: What about Gohan then?

Comment: After the bu saga, Gohan stopped training because his mother forced him. This clearly made him weaker, in the Golden Freezer movie we could verify it. Probably trunks also surpassed Gohan. 
Anyway, Dragon Ball GT is not a canon, it is made by fans, and Toriyama simply gave it the go-ahead.

Comment: Hhh.. Besides, as for as the whole DB story is concerned, either you go with GT series or you go with Super; it is sad that both can not be reconciled. ;( I follow GT!

Comment: Yes it is xD ..

Answer (score 0):

The reason Baby was able to take over the Saiyans even Vegeta is because when he makes it to earth, we see some people he's already planted his egg inside and when he finally reveals himself, he's grown bigger which just basically means he's more powerful, and with this little bit extra bit of power, he was able to take over Saiyans but after they've been exhausted or damaged.